# DBT cloud connection setup with different hosts in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

I am currently using a Redshift data warehouse to connect with my dbt project. We typically have 2 different hosts for development and production databases. I want to trigger jobs during PRs to 2 different branches where one job should run on our development database and the other on our production database(these 2 databases have 2 different host addresses). How do I configure `dbt Cloud` to use two different hosts in the same project? For dbt core, I was able to configure this using profiles.yml and env variables. Will dbt cloud by default use `profiles.yml`? or is there any other way I need to consider to achieve this?

Comment: Each DBT Cloud project can only have one destination. I think the only way to achieve what you're looking for is to create a 2nd project with a different destination configuration but the same and connect to the same Github repo.